# Sudden Memory Leaks Issue

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, mfc, c-strings

Environment:
Windows 10 Home 10.0.16299

MS Visual Studio Community 2017 Version 15.6.6

Compile Settings: 64 bit - Multi-Byte Char Set

Since a few days, I'm facing a very annoying issue of memory leaks. I tried a lot but the problems still remains.

Suddently, I got the following messages on application exit :

```
{7196} normal block at 0x000001FD42D0EA90, 66 bytes long.
 Data: <`  f    )   )   > 60 C6 CC 66 F7 7F 00 00 29 00 00 00 29 00 00 00 

f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\oleinit.cpp(84) : {749} client block at 0x000001FD40F735F0, subtype c0, 104 bytes long.

f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\dumpcont.cpp(23) : atlTraceGeneral - a CCmdTarget object at $000001FD40F735F0, 104 bytes long

f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\plex.cpp(29) : {747} normal block at 0x000001FD40F78750, 248 bytes long. Data: <                > 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 

f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\occmgr.cpp(794) : {746} normal block at 0x000001FD40F5F1D0, 8 bytes long.
 Data: <   f    > F0 BB A3 66 F7 7F 00 00
```

and also I got the following messages on application exit (I got 12 in fact)

```
{348} normal block at 0x00000236C88FE4A0, 69 bytes long.
 Data: <` >     ,   ,   > 60 C6 3E BE F6 7F 00 00 2C 00 00 00 2C 00 00 00
```

So, when I add the following line.....

```
_CrtSetBreakAlloc(348);
```

The compiler breaks with the message The xxxx.exe has triggered a breakpoint.

Always a the same place: the line

```
'pData = (CStringData*)malloc( nTotalSize );' in  CAfxStringMgr::Allocate

CStringData* CAfxStringMgr::Allocate( int nChars, int nCharSize ) throw()
{
    size_t nTotalSize;
    CStringData* pData;
    size_t nDataBytes;

    ASSERT(nCharSize > 0);

    if(nChars < 0)
    {
        ASSERT(FALSE);
        return NULL;
    }

    nDataBytes = (nChars+1)*nCharSize;
    nTotalSize = sizeof( CStringData )+nDataBytes;
    pData = (CStringData*)malloc( nTotalSize );
    if (pData == NULL)
        return NULL;
    pData->pStringMgr = this;
    pData->nRefs = 1;
    pData->nAllocLength = nChars;
    pData->nDataLength = 0;

    return pData;
}
```

The problem arised with function that passed CString as reference parameter. Like this one:

```
int CFoo::GetData(CString strMainData, CString& strData, int nPos, int nLen)
{
    strData = strMainData.Mid(nPos + 2, nLen);

    return ( nPos + 2 + nLen);
}
```

Any clue why I got this ? I'm working on that app since several weeks. I never experienced this issue. I modified the function to use char* as parameter and the, a copy to the CSring in the calling function but the problem remains. This behaviour appeared two weeks ago (but I didn't notice it directly). Could it be a compiler settings ?

Comment: Are you calling `free()` for the memory you allocate via `Allocate()`?

Comment: Please show the definition of `CStringData`; is it a POD ("plain old datatype")?

Comment: `CStringData` and the `CAfxStringMgr::Allocate` function are part of the Microsoft Foundation Classes (MFC).

Comment: Where's the code that calls `CFoo::GetData`?  It appears that that code is where the object that is not being destroyed is, resulting in the memory leak.

Comment: Afaik, CString class performs the clean up automatically. Allocate() and free() are never called by the applications using CString

Comment: The code that calls CFoo::GetData is part of a class, declared as a member of the application class CxxxxApp.

Comment: You should [edit] the question to include the code that calls `CFoo::GetData`.

Comment: Please try to prepare a [mcve]. Memory leaks are not caused by allocating stuff, but by forgetting to release it, hence only a complete example can demonstrate your issue

Comment: If you have a source code management system (such as git), roll back until to the version that doen't have the problem and then find out at which version the problem occurs. That's one of the reasons to use a source code management systerm.

Comment: The code you've shown is not the culprit. It's part of `CString`'s implementation, that you can assume to be correct. The issue is with the code calling into it. This could be one of two things: This is a genuine resource leak. Move up the callstack until you find a dynamic allocation that never gets released. It's also possible, that the CRT leak detection got confused. This often happens with singleton implementations that rely on objects with static storage duration. Destruction of those objects is sometimes scheduled to run *after* the leak detection has concluded an issue.

Comment: You can also get messages like that if you mix and match MBCS and Unicode DLLs that use MFC. In my own experience, we have a MBCS application. When we call into one of our other DLLs that is Unicode via COM, then we get a bunch of similar warnings. If we don't call into that particular DLL, no warnings. If another Unicode application of ours calls into that particular, no warnings. Has something to do with how the runtime is managing strings. (all this is in debug builds)

Comment: Thank you for all your ideas.. I'll continue checking the reasons for this behaviour. Up to now, I got no results. I'll keep you informed

Comment: I finally gave up !!! I restarted the application from scratch. It took me 2 weeks only. And no more memory leaks....
Thank you all for your help and advices